# Command+V Doesn't work on liquid Damaged keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard, damage

I'm wondering if its possible for the command key to be partially broken by liquid damaged keyboard (Macbook Air).

I have 3 confirmed keys that don't work: period, comma, and downarrow. Everything else seems to be okay on this system.

However, Command+V for paste doesn't work using the left command key. Other shortcuts  work fine, like cut/copy/spotlight, using the same left command key. The right command key works for everything.

It seems to me like left command is somehow damaged as well but why would only command+v fail?

Comment: ⌘V works with the right ⌘ but not the left? and all the other combinations work with the left, just not V?

Comment: Correct. I haven't tested every shortcut that exists, but so far, Leftcommand+V doesn't work, rightcommand+V works, and other keyboard shortcuts work on both command keys.